# how to lazily define a class in a puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

I have a system which has different roles, A B C. There is a class `daemon::conf` that defines  the conf and concats the configs of all the classes arguments e.g.

```
class daemon::conf (
  global_config = {}
  a_config      = {}
  b_config      = {}
  c_config      = {}
) {
concat::fragment {...}
}
```

So when I do this:

```
class hg_mysystem::mycluster::hybrid {
  include daemon::A
  include daemon::B
}
```

I want to have:

```
$ cat /etc/mysystem/config
[Global]
...
[A]
...
[B]
...
```

each daemon is defined as `daemon::A, daemon::B, daemon::C`, but they call `daemon::conf` with heir own parameters that are either defined in hiera on inside the `.pp` manifest files. Now I need to create a node that has 2 or 3 roles (writing `include daemon::A;include daemon::B` etc), but I get a problem with a class redefinition, because daemon::conf is defined in all A B and C.

My first thought was to define the class on one node and add `if defined(Class['daemon::conf']) {add argument to the defined class} else {class{'daemon::conf'...}}` but I don't know how to create a dynamic hiera variable from a manifest, or how to do a hiera style assignment from a manifest.
I was also searching on how to do a lazy init of the class with those virtual resources, but I don't understand how could that help, when realize doesn't override an argument but with realize you only do this `realise Class['daemon::conf']` and not `realise Class['daemon::conf'] {b_config={...}}`.
Is there any way I can restructure `daemon::conf` with subclasses that notify another class that builds the conf based on the classes' data.

**Edit:**

I followed the second approach and split `daemon::conf` to `daemon::conf`, `daemon::conf::A`, `daemon::conf::B`

```
class daemon::conf (...) {
  concat { '/etc/daemon/conf':
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0664',
    require => Package['daemon'],
  }

  Concat::Fragment <<| target == '/etc/daemon/config' |>>

  concat::fragment { 'daemon.conf':
    tag     => "daemon.conf",
    target  => '/etc/daemon/config',
    order   => '01',
    content => template('daemon/daemon.conf.erb'),
  }
}

define daemon::conf::A (...) {
  include ::daemon::conf

  @@concat::fragment { "${::hostname}.daemon.conf":
    tag     => "daemon.conf",
    target  => '/etc/daemon/config',
    order   => '20',
    content => template('daemon/daemon.conf-A.erb'),
  }

}

class daemon::conf::B (...) {
  include ::daemon::conf

  concat::fragment { $::hostname:
    tag     => "daemon.conf",
    target  => '/etc/daemon/config',
    order   => '10',
    content => template('daemon/daemon.conf-B.erb'),
  }

}

class daemon::A (
  $A_addr,
  $port,
) {
  include ::daemon::conf

  daemon::conf::A { $::hostname:
    addr => $A_addr,
    port => $port,
  }
}

class daemon::B (
  $B_rack_loc,
) {
  include ::daemon::conf

  class {'::daemon::conf::B':
    B_config => {
      B_rack_location => $B_rack_loc,
    }
  }
}
```

Running puppet on 3 nodes in the same hostgroup I should get:

```
[user@hostname1: ~]$ cat /etc/daemon/config
[Global]
...
[B]
loc = row RO, rack RA, host hostname1
[A/hostname1 ip]
addr=...
port=...
[A/hostname2 ip]
addr=...
port=...
[A/hostname3 ip]
addr=...
port=...
```

But instead I get multiple configs of role B as well of all 3 hosts. What mistake do I do and how to fix it? Thanks. Is it the "<<| |>>" statement that should be altered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution needs to accommodate the fact that the values of *all* of a given class's parameters are determined the first time a declaration of that class is evaluated, whether the declaration is a resource-like one or an include-like one.  Multiple declarations are permitted only if all those evaluated after the first use one of the include-like forms, and this is among the reasons that resource-like class declarations should be avoided under most circumstances.

There are various ways to take those considerations into account.  One would be to invert the logic: instead of having all each `daemon::X` class declare `daemon::conf`, declare it once, centrally, and pass it a list of roles to configure.  Let it then declare appropriate `daemon::conf::X` classes based on the role list:

```
class daemon::conf (
  $global_config = {}
  $roles =         []
) {
  concat { ... }
  concat::fragment {...}
  $roles.each { |$role|
    contain "daemon::conf::${role}"
  }
}
```

---

Another way would be to absolve the central `daemon::conf` class from responsibility for declaring the per-role configuration at all.  This is possible because you're using Concat to build your config from fragments.  One of the key features of puppetlabs::concat is that `concat::fragment`s can be declared independently of each other and of the `concat` declaring the file to which they contribute:

```
class daemon::conf (
  $global_config = {}
) {
  concat { ... }
  concat::fragment {...}  # general configuration only
}

class daemon::a::conf (...) {
  concat::fragment {...}  # daemon A configs
}

class daemon::b::conf (...) {
  concat::fragment {...}  # daemon B configs
}

class daemon::a (...) {
  include daemon::conf     # (maybe)
  contain daemon::a::conf
  # ...
}

class daemon::b (...) {
  include daemon::conf     # (maybe)
  contain daemon::b::conf
  # ...
}

...
```

Comment: if i could write every parameter in hiera i wouldn't have a problem with my current implementation. now with your first example, how would daemon::B add a parameter from its manifest so `contain "daemon::conf::${role}"` would include the parameterised class instead. should i move all the config logic of each role into the central config class?

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης, for something like your present implementation to work, you would at least need to change from resource-like class declarations of class `daemon::conf` to include-like ones.  Having all the parameter data in Hiera would facilitate that, but would not be enough in itself.  In particular, multiple resource-like declarations of the same class are not permitted even if none of them specify any parameters.

Comment: In response to the question, the first alternative depends on `daemon::conf` one way or another having all the information needed to emit proper configuration for every role.  If you need the `daemon::a`, *etc*. classes to determine configuration properties dynamically, then the second alternative is much more viable.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I have now this small problem I wrote in the edited question and I am done

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης, I don't see any need to export or collect `concat::fragment` resources for your particular purpose.  Just declare them as ordinary resources, as already shown in this answer. (And there is no need, then, to collect them, for they will already be in the catalog.)